# How to skip question in Microsoft bot framework waterfall dialog model Python based on existing data or condition

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot

I am developing a chatbot to collect information about the application in use. as of now I have a waterfall model which ask the following questions about the application to the owner

1. what is the description of the application
2. what is the installation date or end date of the application
3. on which server application is installed?
4. what is the operating system for the application?
   and so on.

However, I need to do this on a conditional basis, for example, if the application description already presents in the repository then the chatbot should skip to the next question. like this, if I already have an answer in the repository chatbot should skip that question.
I already check component dialog - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python

Could you please point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? I am quite new to the Microsoft bot framework.